# How to obtain a scala.reflect.Manifest from a type parameter

Tags: scala

We have  an existing API that require a `scala.reflect.Manifest` . The api requires invocation like this:

```
 def extractConfig[C: Manifest](config: JObject) : C
```

.  What we have to work with is:

```
abstract class MyApp[T <: MyType[T], U <: MyOtherType] extends App
```

Is there a way to obtain a `scala.reflect.Manifest` for `U` just given the definition shown above ?  Something like this:

```
 abstract class MyApp[T <: MyType[T], U <: MyOtherType : Manifest] extends App {
 ..
 val jsonObj: JObject = getJson()
 val cfg: U = extractConfig[U](jsonObj)  // "No manifest found for Type U"
```

However the `U <: MyOtherType : Manifest` does not work: it ***does compile***. But at runtime we have

> No manifest found for type U

on the noted line.

Is there some detail that may be added to the type declarations to get the Manifest set up properly?

** Update **  The core issue is the `Json4s` api that requires a `Manifest`. It is not clear why that were the case: i.e. why is `Json4s` unable to determine the `Manifest` itself for *any* type parameter.

Invocation code:

```
 val cfg = parse(readResource(path)).extract[C]
```

`Json4s` source code:
https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala#L20-#L21

```
def extract[A](implicit formats: Formats, mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A =
  Extraction.extract(jv)(formats, mf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you got the error message as this is the correct way of doing so (maybe you could post the code for U), however, doing : manifest is just a syntactic sugar for (implicit ev: manifest[U]) so you could do:

```
abstract class MyApp[T <: MyType[T], U <: MyOtherType](implicit ev: manifest[U]) extends App
```

BTW, in scala 2.11 and on, the suggested replacement for manifest are TypeTags and ClassTag (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)

Comment: I have used TypeTag and ClassTag for several years now but am working with someone else's pride and joy codebase. Why they are using the `Manifest` is an archaeological inquiry. Also that means that using the `implicit ev: manifest[U]` can not be done as shown: I *must* use an already baked Type Parameter instead.

Comment: Aha! Looks like it were an artifact of `Json4s`.  Am updating the OP

Comment: The invocation of `extract` in `Json4s` requires a type parameter, not an instance of manifest: specifically `val cfg = parse(readResource(path)).extract[C]`   The `C` must be a type parameter with `: Manifest`.  It would be much easier if could send in the `evidence (ev)` but that approach does not appear to be available.

Comment: Working through including trying out `ClassTag`.  Will upvote your answer as it in the general region of things that were likely to be useful.